# Is communication between two ruby processes possible/easy?

Tags: ruby, communication, interprocess

If I have a ruby script `Daemon` that, as it's name implies, runs as a daemon, monitoring parts of the system and able to perform commands which require authentication, for example changing permissions, is there an easy way to have a second ruby script, say `client`, communicate to that script and send it commands / ask for information? I'm looking for a built in ruby way of doing this, I'd prefer to avoid building my own server protocol here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby provides many mechanisms for this including your standards such as: [sockets](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/socket/rdoc/index.html), [pipes](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#M002247), [shared memory](http://raa.ruby-lang.org/project/mmap/). But ruby also has a higher level library specifically for IPC which you can checkout [Here](http://stdlib.rubyonrails.org/libdoc/drb/rdoc/index.html), Drb. I haven't had a chance to play around with it too much but it looks really cool.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into http://rubyeventmachine.com/